# How to create an abstract subclass of SQLAlchemy's Table(Base) class

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy to create tables in my project. I have a requirement where all these tables should have some specific attributes and functions. I want to create a structure such that all tables inherit from an abstract class which includes these attributes and functions.

Here's an example of what I want to achieve:

```py
Base = declarative_base()
# pseudo
class Table(ABC, Base):
    # like @abstractattribute
    some_attribtue = list()
    @staticmethod
    def some_func(self):
        pass
class Users(Table):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    user_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String, nullable=False)
    some_attribute = list()
    @staticmethod
    def some_func():
        do_something()
```

By doing this, I hope that I can use these classes in something like:

```py
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

while also being able to call:

```py
Users.some_func()
```

I understand that this code wouldn't work as is, due to issues like having ABC and Base at the same time, not having `@abstractattribute`, and needing to add `__tablename__` and a Primary-Key Column to the class Table.

I am thinking of using a decorator to achieve this, but I am not sure how to implement it correctly. This is the outline of my idea:

```py
class Table(ABC):
    some_attribute=None
    @staticmethod
    def some_func(self):
        pass
# create decorator
def sql_table():
    def decorator(abstract_class):
        class SQLTable(Base): # How do I name the class correctly?
            __tablename__ = abstract_class.__dict__["__tablename__"]
            some_attribute = abstract_class.__dict__["some_attribute"]
            for name, obj in abstract_class.__dict__.items():
                if isinstance(obj, Column):
                    locals()[name] = obj
            # How do I get the some_func function?
@sql_table
class Users(Table):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    user_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String, nullable=False)
    some_attribute = "some_val"
    @staticmethod
    def some_func():
        do_something()
```

Any help or suggestions on how to implement this (not necessarily with decorators) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can pass a class to `declarative_base` - check the documentation.

Comment: Damn, I think you're right. I'll try to figure it out in my own project. If it works, I'll post an answer. Might take me a while though.

Comment: There is also [`__abstract__`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/declarative_config.html#abstract) (which you can also set on the class that you pass to `declarative_base`.

Comment: Sounds like OP wants to [augment the base](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/declarative_mixins.html#augmenting-the-base).

Comment: I think there are indeed multiple simple ways to achieve this. I have found a solution that works in my local project. I will now create an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [@snakecharmerb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5320906/snakecharmerb) and [@ljmc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17676984/ljmc) I have found an solution that works for me, although there seem to be many ways one can achieve this.

The solution that works for me is:

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base, declared_attr
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String


Base = declarative_base()


class Table(Base):
    __abstract__ = True
    
    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls) -> str: # so i don't have to specify no more
        return cls.__name__.lower()
    
    some_attribute = set() # this is the default
    
    @staticmethod
    def some_func(): # define default behavior (or pass)
        do_something()


class Users(Table):
    # define columns as usual
    user_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String, nullable=False)

    some_attribute = set(["a"]) # overwrite the default

    def some_func(): # overwrite the default behavior
        do_something_else()
```

Now, this should be improved upon by specifying a type to some_attribute (typing is awesome).